# Comment traduire « one-off » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, économie, adjectifs

Comment traduit-on *one-off* qui à le sens d'un paiement dont on doit payer le montant une fois au lieu d'une série de paiements réguliers.

Google propose le traduction *paiement ponctuel* mais je ne suis pas convaincu que c'est la  meilleure traduction.

Comment: Juste une remarque périphérique: "one-off" ne me semble pas le terme naturel pour indiquer un paiement en une seule fois ("one-time payment" serait la tournure standard). En général, "one-off" s'applique plutôt à un événement (unique) et se traduirait complètement différemment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je ne vois pas de traduction parfaitement satisfaisante qui tiendrait en un seul adjectif.

J'opterais pour une périphrase "payer en une fois", "effectuer un paiement unique" ou n'importe quelle tournure avoisinante.

Le "paiement ponctuel" me paraît envisageable, mais l'expression me semble moins claire que "payer en une fois" et ne recouvre pas exactement l'idée d'unicité.

Par contre, "payer comptant" ne traduit pas l'idée de payer en une fois, mais l'idée de payer dans un délai bref (et de préférence en liquide) comme le "to pay cash" anglais dont il me parait être l'équivalent (cf [TLF, sens IV](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comptant)).

Comment: "paiement ponctuel" me plait aussi, mais semble légèrement ambigu (pourrait se comprendre comme la nécessité de payer *dans les temps*).

Comment: Pour les différences régionales sur le sens de *payer comptant* cf http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/etendue-geographique-de-comptant-argent-liquide

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que l'expression qui convient est *payer comptant*.

Comment: Hey! Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

L'expression que j'entends le plus souvent est "payer en une fois". Cependant Evpok a très justement cité la formule "payer comptant" qui est l'expression canonique.

Answer (score 3):

A mon avis *payer comptant* implique aussi de payer immédiatement, ce que ne veut peut-être pas nécessairement dire *one-off*.

Je préfererais *payer en une fois*. C'est aussi ce qu'on [peut](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/one-off) [trouver](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/one-off/598920) via [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=traduction%20one-off).

<strike>Et pour ajouter une réponse qui n'a pas encore été mentionnée, *ponctuel* peut être une traduction de *one-off* mais je ne pense pas l'avoir jamais entendue dans le cadre de moyens de paiement.</strike> Ouuups, ça a été mentionné dans la question :-/

Comment: +1 paiement ponctuel me semble être la meilleure traduction

Comment: @FrançoisFeugeas Ponctuel? Dans quel sens? (->http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/ponctuel)

Comment: Dans le sens 3 et par opposition à paiement récurrent ; "one-off" mettant l'accent sur le caractère non récurrent ("one-shot", malheureusement très employé en finance en Français). "Paiement comptant" ne me parait pas adapté, mettant l'emphase sur l'aspect immédiat, non impliqué par "one-off".

Answer (score 2):

"Payer comptant" me paraît fort bien car rien n'indique le mode de paiement en français (liquide, chèque ou carte bancaire). "En une fois" est une périphrase également usitée.
Par contre, dans d'autres contextes, "one-off" se rendra par "unique", exceptionnel", etc.
Par contre "paiement ponctuel" pourrait signifier à la rigueur "en temps et en heure"; l'expression n'est d'ailleurs guère usitée.

Comment: +1 pour paiement unique, lorsqu'il s'agit de payer à une date qui ne correspond pas forcément avec la date de commande ou de livraison. - *comptant* s'emploie surtout lorsque l'on paie à l'enlèvement de le marchandise