# Étendue géographique de « comptant » = argent liquide

Tags: choix-de-mot, régionalismes

Je suis canadien, et ai toujours appelé l'argent liquide « comptant » (par exemple, « Nous n'acceptons pas les cartes bancaires, il faut payer comptant. »).  J'habite à Bruxelles maintenant, et j'ai l'impression qu'on dit « cash » ou « liquide » au lieu de dire « comptant ».

Un collègue français m'a affirmé que *comptant* est un québécisme.  Ma question est donc de savoir s'il a raison.
Est-ce que *comptant* dans ce sens est un québécisme ? Qu'est-ce que je devrais dire à la place en France ou en Belgique ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pour moi (français) *payer comptant* met l'accent sur payer quelque chose « immédiatement et dans sa totalité » (qui semble confirmé par l'[academie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/comptant)). Le fait que le moyen de paiement choisi soit du liquide ou non n'importe pas vraiment. Si l'on veut exprimer que le paiement est fait avec des pièces et des billets, « payer en liquide » ou « payer en espèces » est la seule solution.

Comment: Je confirme, tout en étant belge, que c'est bien de cela qu'il s'agit. Le terme "payer comptant" a une conotation "légale" ou "formelle". On voit cela plus dans les contrats de vente que dans le language oral, même si tout le monde en Belgique comprendra que quoi il s'agit.

Comment: Payer en liquide se dit aussi !

Comment: Suivant le contexte (si je parle à quelqu'un d'autre que le vendeur), je n'utiliserais même pas « comptant » si j'ai emprunté pour effectuer le payement, même si le vendeur a reçu toute la somme sans jouer les intermédiaires.

Comment: Le TLFI indique que «comptant» comme synonyme de «liquide» est «Vx,fam».  Si je comprends bien, ça veut dire que cet usage est resté courant, mais seulement dans un registre familier?

Answer (score 6):

En France on parle d'**espèces** pour ce que tu décris.

Voici un lien sur la définition de [*paiement en espèces*](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/F10999.xhtml) sur le site officiel de l'administration française.
Emploi de *paiement en espèces* dans un [texte de loi français](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006169848&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072026&dateTexte=vig).

La définition de Stéphane Gimenez sur le *paiement comptant* est confirmée par le [TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?38;s=2841049605;r=3;nat=;sol=0;) et en France un *paiement au comptant* n'est pas nécessairement effectué en espèces.

Comment: Le lien vers le TLF est lié à une session expirée. Était-ce celui-là `http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comptant` ?

Answer (score 4):

Payer comptant signifie payer avec un moyen de payement « qui se compte sur le champ », c'est-à-dire un payement immédiat (pas de délais).

En l'occurrence, seule la monnaie (argent liquide, cash, …) est un moyen de payement immédiat maintenant.

Cela se dit en France couramment et je ne vois pas de raison pour laquelle l'expression ne serait pas générale à la francophonie. Après, l'usage est peut-être plus répandu dans certaines régions.

Answer (score 3):

C'est dur à dire, étant moi-même Québécois, mais ni mon Larousse, ni mon Grevisse, ni mon de Villers (et dieu que de Villers n'est pas une fan des québécismes!) ne disent quoi que ce soit là-dessus. Ce qui s'en approche le plus est une mention qualifiant « cash » de familier sous l'entrée « comptant », ce qui indique peut-être que ce dernier est vu comme plus technique.

À la lueur des autres réponses, il semblerait qu'au Québec, on oppose le sens « payer en liquide » au sens « payer par chèque/carte de crédit/paiement différé », alors qu'en France, on oppose plutôt le sens de « payer la totalité immédiatement » au sens de « paiement différé » (« paiement différé » du genre pour une maison, une voiture, du mobilier ou autre en plusieurs versements).

Les deux sens *sont reconnus valides*, mais les oppositions de sens semblent différentes au Québec et à Bruxelles. Quant à savoir *l'étendue géographique* de ces oppositions, c'est une autre histoire, et il est possible, voire probable, que personne ne puisse donner une réponse vraiment précise.

Comment: Je me demande si c'est parce qu'en Europe, les paiements qui ne sont pas en espèces se font principalement par virement bancaire ou par carte bancaire, et donc sont comptants par cette définition.  Par contre, chez nous, si on ne paie pas en espèces, c'est souvent parce qu'on utilise une carte de crédit, et donc un emprunt.

Comment: J'avoue que j'en doute: du point de vue _du vendeur_, un paiment par carte de crédit est " immédiatement et total" (pour utiliser la définition de "comptant" que Stéphane applique). Toutefois je dois dire que mon expérience est atypique car je n'ai pas de carte de crédit, pas plus que plusieurs de mes amis proches...

Comment: En outre (par rapport a ce dernier commentaire), beaucoup de ce que les gens appellent "cartes de crédit" en France, lorsqu'elles sont émises par de banques et non des institutions de crédit, sont en fait des cartes de débit, voire à débit différé (contrairement à d'autres pays où on a une facture séparée). Dans ces cas la, "comptant" peut aussi marcher par carte, effectivement.

Comment: De fait, les cartes de débit sont *très* communes ici, au point où certaines institutions offrent des cartes qui combinent le débit et le crédit (par ex. Desjardins et Visa).

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas compétent de répondre à votre question spécifique (je suis en train d'apprendre le français en Québec!) Mais j'ai trouvé une bonne source, le site-web de L'office québécoise de la langue française.  Là-dedans ils utilisent [le mot «comptant»](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/gdt.html) pour indiquer:

> un paiement effectué ou d'une opération réglée en numéraire, par carte
>   de débit ou par chèque **portant la somme totale**, sans terme ni crédit.
>    Synonymes:
>                 cash  [familier],
>                 au comptant

et contrairement ils utilisent la phrase «en numéraire» pour:

> un paiement en monnaie (billets ou pièces) par opposition au paiement
>   par chèque, carte de crédit, etc. 
>   Synonyme(s):
>          en liquide,
>          comptant,
>          cash,
>          au comptant

C'est moi qui ai mis la phrase «portant la somme totale» en caractères gras.  Je crois que cette définition renforce l'interprétation de Stéphane [au dessus](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2193/858).

Comment: Merci pour la référence.  C'est vrai que la définition (1) de «comptant» est celle que tu cites, mais la définition (2) est la suivante :
«Se dit d'un paiement en monnaie (billets ou pièces) par opposition au paiement par chèque, carte de crédit, etc.»